# Accessing HTMLElement results in memory leak?

Tags: vb.net, memory, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control, vb.net-2010

I noticed my program was using an absurd (and ever-increasing) amount of memory, and managed to narrow it down to this piece of code:

```
        Dim elements As HtmlElementCollection = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each ce As HtmlElement In elements
        If ce.GetAttribute("hidden") = "false" Then ce.Style = "Display:none"
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ce.DomElement)
    Next
```

I'm using it to hide some specific elements on a webpage loaded by a WebBrowser control. I'm accessing a lot of webpages sequentially using a new WebBrowser instance each time (making sure to dispose of it afterwards), which means the above code gets run pretty frequently.

After commenting it out, memory usage stays relatively low and constant. But as soon as I add the code back in, memory usage increases dramatically, and keeps growing without ever going back down again.

I added the "Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ce.DomElement)" line after doing some research about the issue, and it's helped, albeit slightly-- memory usage still increases until the program crashes.

Again, everything works fine when I comment this section of code out, so I can verify the problem isn't being caused by some other oversight elsewhere.

Does anyone know what I could do to fix this, or know of some alternative method I can use to accomplish the same thing without the memory issue?

**Edit:** Also, I just want to point out that using a WebClient is out of the question-- I need the webpage to be rendered so I can take a screenshot.

**Edit #2:** In case anyone else is having a similar problem, I ended up using JavaScript instead, to the same effect:

```
wb.Navigate("document.getElementsByClassName('item')[0].setAttribute('style','display:none');")
```

That fixed the memory issue. However, I'm still interested in knowing why the original method used up so much memory, and how I could avoid that in the future...